# How to travel up avoiding use parent() function

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I am trying to travel up from `$('.sent_comment_action')` to `.message_to_comment` element with the following structure:

```
<div class="replay_comment_container">
    <input type="hidden" class="message_to_comment" name="message_to_comment" value="1234" />
    <a class="new_comment_action" href="#">Add Comment</a>
    <div class="comment_form">
        <form>
            <textarea class="comment_field" name="comment_body"></textarea>
            <input class="sent_comment_action" type="submit" value="Send" />
            <div class="error"></div>
        </form>
    </div>                    
</div>
```

Just because the markup can be repeatable in same page, it is not enought to get the id of the message to comment as below:

```
var message_id = $('.message_to_comment').val();
```

As I have `$('.sent_comment_action')` as a context of the message that will be commented, I could travel up using:

```
//button in question
var message_id = button.parent().parent()... find('.message_to_comment').val();
```

But I don't like the idea of having a thousand of parent() functions. So, my sencond try was using the `closest()` function as below:

```
var message_id = button.closest('.message_to_comment').val();
```

When I test the code above, looks like the element `.message_to_comment` is never found because it returns an "indefined". So, could please guide to right direction in order to get a better solucion instead using parent() function (if exists another way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, you want to look for an element that is not a parent of the button, it is in fact a sibling of the closest `.comment_form`

```
button.closest('.replay_comment_container').children('.message_to_comment').val();
```

You could also try

```
button.closest('.comment_form').prevAll('.message_to_comment').val();
```

Comment: Both of them work perfect, I appreciate your help. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

The input with class `message_to_comment` isn't a parent of your button.

It seems you could use

```
button.closest('replay_comment_container').find('.message_to_comment').val();
```

Comment: Using `.replay_comment_container` works as expected :) Now I know why `closest()` does not found the element.

Answer (score 0):

How about using while loop:

```
function getValue(element) 
{
   var parent = element;

   do 
   {
      parent = parent.parent();
      element = parent.find('.message_to_comment');
   }
   while (!element && parent)

   return element ? element.val() : null;
}
```

you can then use:

```
var myValue = getValue(valbutton);
```

Comment: Maybe you should look at the HTML, you know guess why he cannot find the element.

Comment: Well it shouldn't be hidden, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question simply, .prev(); : For previous element is the method your looking for. 
But I'd suggest this to change your code a little bit to make it easier to find elements using jQuery selectors.

```
<div class="replay_comment_container">
<a class="new_comment_action" href="#">Add Comment</a>
<div class="comment_form">
    <form name="form1" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" class="message_to_comment" name="message_to_comment" value="1234" />
        <textarea class="comment_field" name="comment_body"></textarea>
        <input class="sent_comment_action" type="submit" value="Send" />
        <div class="error"></div>
    </form>
</div>                    
</div>
```

now for your jQuery selector

```
$('.send_comment_action').click(function(){
    /*prevent form submitting */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* selector for multiple .replay_comment_container's */
    var value = $(this).prev().prev().val();
    /*a prev method I haven't tried but i believe is the best and correct method */
    var value = $(this).prev('.message_to_send').val();
    /* selector for single .replay_comment_container */
    var value = $('input[name="message_to_comment"]','.replay_comment_container').val();
});
```